# EF 6 - Code first invalid one-to-one foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

**DESIGN BACKGROUND**:

I'm trying to create code-first EF6 mappings for the following database structure:

The database design is as follow: Instead of having "CustomerID" as foreign key on all related entities (Employment, expenses, income, etc...), we have a CustomerRelationship table, which will contain the CustomerID, and then a "RelatedID" column which will contain the key of the related entity. For instance, lets say I add an employment record for CustomerID=1, then the following will happen:

> 1. Create record in CustomerRelationship, setting CustomerID = 1 RelatedID = {new autogenerated EmploymentID, lets say 5}
>      CustomerRelationshipTypeID = 55 (Id in lookup table which states that
>      this record is of type employment)
> 2. Create record in Employment table (EmploymentID=5)

**The above structure will work for all entities tied to a Customer.**

[image: DB Diagram]
I have relationship mappings working for Employment, here are my classes:

```
public abstract class EntityBase : IEntity
{
    #region IEntity Members
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int CreatedUserId { get; set; }

    public int CreatedSource { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public int ModifiedUserId { get; set; }

    public int? DataMigrationId { get; set; } 

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }                                    
    #endregion
}


public class Employment : EntityBase
{
    // ... all properties here.. removed most so easier to read
    public int EmploymentTypeId { get; set; }    

    **public virtual ICollection<EmploymentRelationship> EmploymentRelationships { get; set; }**
}

    public EmploymentMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        ToTable("tblEmployment");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("EmploymentID");    
        // Mapping for all properties follow       
    }

public abstract partial class CustomerRelationship : EntityBase
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public decimal? PercentageShare { get; set; }

    public int CustomerRelationshipTypeId { get; set; }

    public int RelatedId { get; set; }
}

public class EmploymentRelationship : CustomerRelationship
{       
    public virtual Employment Employment { get; set; }
}

    public EmploymentRelationshipMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Map<EmploymentRelationship>(m =>
        {
            m.Requires("CustomerRelationshipTypeID").HasValue(55).IsRequired(); // Define lookup value for type of employment
            m.ToTable("tblCustomerRelationship");
        });

        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("CustomerRelationshipID");
        Property(t => t.CustomerId).HasColumnName("CustomerID");
        Property(t => t.RelatedId).HasColumnName("RelatedID");

        HasRequired(t => t.Employment)
            .WithMany(t => t.EmploymentRelationships)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.RelatedId);
    }

public class Customer : EntityBase
{
    // Customer Properties...
    public Customer()
    {
        EmploymentRelationships = new List<EmploymentRelationship>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<EmploymentRelationship> EmploymentRelationships { get; set; }
}

    public CustomerMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        ToTable("tblCustomer");

        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("CustomerID");
    }


public class CustomerContext 
{
    public CustomerContext()
        : base(SymmetryCopy.context_connectionstring_main)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Employment> Employments { get; set; }

    #region Customer Relationship entity mappings
    public virtual DbSet<EmploymentRelationship> EmploymentRelationships { get; set; }
    #endregion

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmploymentMap());

        #region Customer Relationship entity mappings
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmploymentRelationshipMap());
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**CustomerRepo to query context and return results:**

```
public class CustomerRepository : BaseRepository<Customer, CustomerContext>, ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository() : 
        base(new CustomerContext())
    {

    }

    public async Task<List<Employment>> GetEmployments(int customerId)
    {
        List<Employment> employments = new List<Employment>();
        using (var context = new CustomerContext())
        {
            var employmentRelationships = context.EmploymentRelationships.Where(l => l.CustomerId == customerId).ToList();
            employments = employmentRelationships.Select(x => x.Employment).ToList();
        }
        return employments;
    }
}
```

The above method **GetEmployments** then returns all records matching CustomerID with CustomerRelationshipTypeID = 55 (Key value for Employments). See returns below.

[image]

Now to get to my actual questions:

When I try and hook up another Entity Type, ie: Expense, following the same approach as that of Employment, creating Expense.cs, ExpenseMap.cs, ExpenseRelationship.cs, ExpenseRelationshipMap.cs, having the following in ExpenseRElationshipMap.cs:

```
public class ExpenseRelationshipMap
{
    public ExpenseRelationshipMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Map<ExpenseRelationship>(m =>
        {
            m.Requires("CustomerRelationshipTypeID").HasValue(60).IsRequired();
            m.ToTable("tblCustomerRelationship");  // Define lookup value for type of Expense
        });

        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("CustomerRelationshipID");
        Property(t => t.CustomerId).HasColumnName("CustomerID");
        Property(t => t.RelatedId).HasColumnName("RelatedID");
        Property(t => t.PercentageShare).HasColumnName("PercentageShare");

        HasRequired(t => t.Expense)
            .WithMany(t => t.ExpenseRelationships)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.RelatedId);
    }
}
```

Once I Created the Map entry, as shown above, when quering the GetEmployments() method, I now get the following exception:

> "The entity types 'ExpenseRelationship' and 'EmploymentRelationship'
>   cannot share table 'tblCustomerRelationship' because they are not in
>   the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key
>   relationship with matching primary keys between them.",

**What an I missing?**

**UPDATE**

As per jjj comments, I have updated my mappings and created a CustomerRelationship.cs base class.

```
public class Employment : EntityBase
{      
    public string EmployerName { get; set; }

    public string EmployerContactFirstName { get; set; }

    public string EmployerContactSurname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmploymentRelationship> EmploymentRelationships { get; set; }
}

public class Expense : EntityBase
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ExpenseRelationship> ExpenseRelationships { get; set; }
}

public abstract class CustomerRelationship : EntityBase
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerRelationshipTypeId { get; set; }

    public int RelatedId { get; set; }
}

public class EmploymentRelationship : CustomerRelationship
{
    public virtual Employment Employment { get; set; }
}

public class ExpenseRelationship: CustomerRelationship
{
    public virtual Expense Expense{ get; set; }
}

public class CustomerRelationshipMap : BaseMap<CustomerRelationship>
{
    public CustomerRelationshipMap()
    {
        ToTable("CustomerRelationship");

        Map<EmploymentRelationship>(m => m.Requires("CustomerRelationshipTypeID").HasValue(55));
        Map<ExpenseRelationship>(m => m.Requires("CustomerRelationshipTypeID").HasValue(60));

        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("CustomerRelationshipID");            
        Property(t => t.CustomerId).HasColumnName("CustomerID");
        Property(t => t.RelatedId).HasColumnName("RelatedID");            
    }

public class EmploymentRelationshipMap : BaseMap<EmploymentRelationship>
{
    public EmploymentRelationshipMap()
    {
        HasRequired(t => t.Employment)
            .WithMany(t => t.EmploymentRelationships)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.RelatedId);
    }
}

public class ExpenseRelationshipMap : BaseMap<ExpenseRelationship>
{
    public ExpenseRelationshipMap()
    {
        HasRequired(t => t.Expense)
            .WithMany(t => t.ExpenseRelationships)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.RelatedId);
    }
}

public class CustomerContext : BaseContext
{
    public CustomerContext()
        : base(context_connectionstring_main)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Employment> Employments { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<CustomerRelationship> CustomerRelationships { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmploymentRelationship> EmploymentRelationships { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ExpenseRelationship> ExpenseRelationships { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmploymentMap());

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerRelationshipMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmploymentRelationshipMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExpenseRelationshipMap());
    }
}
```

When I query the customer context like this:

```
var relationships = context.CustomerRelationships.Where(l => l.CustomerId == customerId).ToList();
```

I get the following exception:

> "The foreign key component 'RelatedId' is not a declared property on
>   type 'EmploymentRelationship'. Verify that it has not been explicitly
>   excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.",

Comment: Ok, that error with the foreign key component makes sense. I guess you can't use a base class property for a derived class foreign key association. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900155/how-to-map-foreign-keys-between-tph-tpt-objects-entity-framework-code-first and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619452/entity-framework-fluent-api-does-not-consider-base-class-properties

Comment: You are using a relational database. Why would you not want to model relationships using relationships?

Answer (score 7):

You need a base class configuration for all the shared properties (including the primary key).

```
public class CustomerRelationshipMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<CustomerRelationship>
{
    public CustomerRelationshipMap()
    {
        ToTable("tblCustomerRelationship");

        Map<EmploymentRelationship>(m => m.Requires("CustomerRelationshipTypeID").HasValue(55));
        Map<ExpenseRelationship>(m => m.Requires("CustomerRelationshipTypeID").HasValue(60));

        HasKey(t => t.Id);
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("CustomerRelationshipID");
        Property(t => t.CustomerId).HasColumnName("CustomerID");
        Property(t => t.RelatedId).HasColumnName("RelatedID");
    }
}
```

Then, you should be able to have the derived-class-specific configuration in the other configuration classes (though, this isn't something I've tried before).

**Edit**

Also, you can't have different foreign key associations for derived classes using the same base class property. There are a few options I can think of, but it would depend on your situation:

1. Separate foreign keys for the association between `EmploymentRelationship`-`Employment` and `ExpenseRelationship`-`Expense`.
2. Giving `Employment` and `Expense` a common base class as well -- though that might defeat the purpose of what you're trying to do....
3. Separate 1:0..1 relationships between `CustomerRelationship` and `Employment`/`Expense` (and getting rid of `EmploymentRelationship` and `ExpenseRelationship`)
4. TPT inheritance where `Employment` and `Expense` inherit from `CustomerRelationship` (and getting rid of `EmploymentRelationship` and `ExpenseRelationship`)

**Sources**

- [Difficulty Concerning EF Code First Fluent API, TPH, and Foreign Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904218/difficulty-concerning-ef-code-first-fluent-api-tph-and-foreign-keys)
- [How to map foreign keys between TPH TPT objects - Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900155/how-to-map-foreign-keys-between-tph-tpt-objects-entity-framework-code-first)

Comment: @FaNIX: Sorry, I had gotten that last part wrong. :-/ I've made an edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "seperate foreign keys for the association with Employment and Expense"

Comment: @FaNIX: I was thinking separate columns for EmploymentId and ExpenseId in CustomerRelationship. Probably not a good solution

Comment: There has to be a better solution to share the RelatedID column in CustomerRelationship

Comment: @FaNIX: If you use RelatedID as the CustomerRelationship primary key as well, it probably wouldn't be too difficult to configure #3 or #4